# How do I get an LG Lic-300 webcam working?

Tags: 10.04, webcam, lg

I use Ubuntu 10.04LTS from the beginning, and throughout that time the only thing that could not succeed was that this webcam is recognized but not working:

> Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0c45:60fc Microdia PC Camera with Mic (SN9C105)

I use Ubuntu 10.04LTS 32bits and the kernel is 2.6.32-32-generic-pae.
As I've been reading recently, which could for the kernel, a new search and I did not find any documentation that satisfactory.

In http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca5xx.html - appears as the webcam support Test and driver: spca5xx/LE - just bought this webcam to work on Linux, taking the version 9.04 on all other it worked, but now 10.04LTS repeats in the case of Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: Unplug your webcam - run `dmesg` - plug into your webcam - rerun `dmesg` - the new output you see, please add that into your question.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not working? Have you tried opening the device in VLC for example?

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep videodev`?

Answer (score 2):

I have found [this](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/mydownloads/) page with a generic driver for this webcam's chip, I know its old but its worth giving a shot.

The problem with Microdia cams is really drivers, there is a huge list of user asking for them and trying to make them work and a very small list of users that actually made these work without problems.

The [page](http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca5xx.html) you refer to is mostly provided for Creative Live! cams and none of those packages supports your cam.

Your device id (*0c45:60fc*) also does not show on the [Ubuntu supported hardware list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/CAPTURE/index.html?start=50&batch=50) so it will be unlikely that you will this one working flawless anytime soon.

For a list of supported webcams in Ubuntu please have a look on [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsMultimediaWebCameras) list.